# Return the 5th column using sql

Tags: sql, partition-by

[image: Table]

For a particular date(as shown in image) where the source is only Android, I want to return the 5th column as true else null using sql

I tried using partition statement to answer the problem, but that seems to give me the same records as rnum

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! I would recommend reading through [SO tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that, try editing this question. Do take care to include [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [tag your RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) and [do not use pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: If the "Only Android" column is already filled like in your image, the answer below should do. If not, use NOT EXISTS to check there are no other entries.

Answer (score 0):

*Try this:*

`select week_start, user_id, source, rnum, case when [Only android] = 1 then 'true' else null from table_name`